compose isSystemInDarkTheme() is not working properly
isSystemInDarkTheme() in compose returns false on following scenario:

Go to Fragment B(built by compose) from Fragment A(built by xml)
Change device theme to dark
Fragment B theme is in dark mode now
Returns Fragment A while system is in dark mode
Open Fragment B again
isSystemInDarkTheme() returns false
Fragment B is being showed in light mode inside of dark mode

here is the code block that I am using:
return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {
                MainTheme {
                    ProvideWindowInsets {
                        val isDarkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme()
                        BuildUI(isDarkTheme = isDarkTheme)
                    }
                }
            }
        }


use LocalConfiguration.current.isNightModeActive

@Rudra still same

if you are using fragment try updating the Boolean value inside onResume , does the app goes in dark mode if you close it once and reopen it.

it doesn't work also. updated the question @Rudra

there could be multiple reasons , why the dark mode is not implemented , check weather  the state of boolean is not changed ( use rememberSaveable) , make an top level parameter to listen to mode changes and update the ui accordingly , also does the dark theme is applied if you close the app and reopen it.

possible answer can be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77669374/23195985

I'm experiencing the same issue where isSystemInDarkTheme() works correctly in MainActivity, but in two other activities, it doesn't function properly in dark mode and returns false. Have you found a solution to fix this? @kokoko
